# Hide custom list columns from the NewFrom, EditForm, notification emails

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've created several custom columns in the Tasks list named *NotifyUser* and *IsUserNotified*. These columns are not supposed to be changed by user. I change them programmatically only. Is there any mechanism to:

1. Hide those columns from the NewForm, EditForm (I wanna use
   existent Forms).
2. Skip executing workflows when any of those two columns been changed.
3. Exclude columns from the notification mails (as long as user doesn't know anything about these columns, there is no need to show them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only can control these things if you are creating your field programmatically or via a [field schema definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979575) (deployment via WSP Solution and a feature):

1. Set the property *Hidden* to `true` in order to hide the field in user forms and views.
2. Refer to: [SharePoint Workflow: how to update the item without triggering the workflow again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2466533/181108)
3. Should be done by 1.

Comment: After I changed _Hidden_ field attr it disappeared from the From and mails. Thanks so much man!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your view by going in List Tools->List->List Settings->Views.
Then click on the name of your List from where you can uncheck the column that u dont want to show to the user and click ok.